# Icon in button is not displayed

Tags: c++, qt, icons, qml

I have no idea what is wrong. Icon in my button is not displayed. I included icon files to my project. This is my qml:

```
    Button {
            id: prevButton
            iconSource: "qrc:/prev.png"
(...)
```

If I change url to invalid I don't get any warning. What could be the cause?

Comment: Which Qt version are you using ? I tried this on Qt 5.3.1 and it works perfectly. Have you made sure the image is in the Qt Resource ? Also can you try another image file i.e outside the Resource ?

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding your project?

Comment: I also have Qt 5.3.1 . Images are in Resources/qml.qrc/ .  Rebuilding project don't solve problem. The thing is, if I even write `iconSource: ""` or `iconSource: "asdasdadasd"` I don't get any error or warning. Earlier I got warnings if path to image was invalid.

Comment: It must be something with my Qt Creator because if I open raedy project in start window eg Music Player there is also no icon in button. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! There was something wrong with Qt Creator. Reinstall helped.